# How can I draw a tiled background image with "ends" on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a bookshelf that tiles horizontally and vertically.  I have three images, ShelfLeft, ShelfMid, and ShelfRight.  ShelfLeft starts each row/shelf, followed by X ShelfMids across the screen, capped off by ShelfRight at the end of each row.

There will be a default of 5 rows, and if more are needed, they shall be able to be added dynamically.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). Use a cell for each of the "ends", and then another single cell for the tiled background.

To make a background repeat, create res/drawable/my_background.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then reference this as the background in your layout by specifying `android:background="@drawable/my_background".

(Source: http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html)

Also worth noting: You might find the [`NinePatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) class useful when creating your "ends".